# sql query to display products that have not been ordered/appear on invoice

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: Tables joined]i have a homework question im having some trouble with. I am asked to a total number of products form our database that have never been sold.
 [image: TABLES]

it should look like this:

```
+--------------------------------------------+
| number of products that have not been sold |
+--------------------------------------------+
|                                        228 |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

I keep getting this:

```
+--------------------------------------------+
| number of products that have not been sold |
+--------------------------------------------+
|                                          0 |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

my query is:

```
SELECT count(*) AS 'number of products that have not been sold'  
FROM orderdetail  
JOIN invoice on invoice.invoiceid=orderdetail.invoiceid  
WHERE productid is null;
```

Answer (score 3):

- Since you want to consider all the products, `product` table must be your starting table in the **Join**.
- Do **Left join** instead of Inner join. Otherwise, Inner Join will eliminate all the product(s) where there is no matching Order row available.
- Join to the `orderDetail` table using `ProductID`
- To count all the product(s) having no order, use [`COUNT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct) function

Try the following:

```
SELECT count(p.ProductID) AS 'number of products that have not been sold'  
FROM product AS p   
LEFT JOIN orderDetail AS od ON od.ProductID = p.ProductID  
WHERE od.productid IS NULL
```

Comment: I seem to still get a total of 0. I also have to mention that product id goes from 1,2,5,6,7,8,10,12 etc so some productid's are missing from the column.

Comment: @cybkty To just get the product id, you can remove `COUNT(DISTINCT p.productID)` and simply use `p.productID`

Comment: @cybkty are you sure that there are some productid(s) which have no matching row in `orderdetail` table ?

Comment: Assuming `ProductID` is the primary key of `product`, there's no need for `DISTINCT` since there can't be duplicates.

Comment: And there's no need for `COUNT(p.ProductID)`, just use `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: @Barmar yes true. I like to avoid (*) and specify the  column in COUNT. It avoids unintended behaviours (sometimes)

Comment: You would need `COUNT(DISTINCT p.ProductID)` if you were counting the products that have been ordered, since a product can be in multiple orders.

Comment: @Barmar I have updated and removed the `DISTINCT` clause.

Comment: I have added a picture of the invoice and orderdetail table as well

Comment: @cybkty please use `left join` not `join`. There is a [difference between Inner and Left Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya it still seems to not work, keep getting 0

Comment: @cybkty there was a typo :-/ please check the updated answer now. It should definitely work!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: leftjoin on product instead of orderdetail:

```
SELECT count(p.productid)
FROM product as p
LEFT JOIN orderdetail as oDetail on p.productid = oDetail.productid
WHERE oDetail.productid IS NULL;
```